# How to write a De-Identifying template in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dlp

I am trying to De Identify certain columns from a CSV file in Google Cloud Services. The CSV file contains 10 columns having ID, FirstName, LastName, D-O-B, etc. I am trying to mask the fields FirstName and LastName to replace them with * character.

I read the procedure to write a deidentifying template from [this link](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/organizations.deidentifyTemplates#DeidentifyTemplate.InfoTypeTransformations).

I am trying to mask only the First Name and Last Name fields using record transformations, however I am getting an ArrayOutOf Bounds error when i'm running the job.

Is It necessary that I have to mention all the columns in the De identification template or only those fields that I need to mask.

The CSV file is something as follows:

```
ID  FirstName   LastName    D_O_B   Facility    EncounterNum    EncounterDate   EncounterTime   visitNum

101 Sean    John    8/27/1968   LI  333 4/8/2016    2018-09-02 13:00:00 UTC 1
501 bla bla 7/13/1947   LI  337 3/14/2016   2018-09-03 21:05:00 UTC 67
851 Julius  Caesar  8/15/1988   LI  339 5/17/2016   2018-09-03 21:25:00 UTC 89
```

The Deidentfication template I am using is as follows:

```
{
  "deidentifyTemplate": {
    "description": "Record transformation on Names trial",
    "deidentifyConfig": {
      "recordTransformations": {
        "fieldTransformations": [
          {
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "FirstName"
              },
              {
                "name": "LastName"
              }
            ],
            "primitiveTransformation": {
              "characterMaskConfig": {
                "maskingCharacter": "*"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the output to be a tabe in BigQuery containing masked FirstName and Lastname columns. I am however getting an Array out of bounds error.

Comment: Do you mind providing the full request you sent via rpc?

Answer (score 0):

Not an exert of the DLP API but I tried the following de-identify configuration and it worked for me. Using the following [endpoint for Cloud DLP API](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.content/deidentify).

```
{
  "item": {
    "value": "My name is John Doe and I live nowhere."
  },
  "inspectConfig": {
    "includeQuote": true,
    "infoTypes": [
      {
        "name": "FIRST_NAME"
      },
      {
        "name": "LAST_NAME"
      }
    ]
  },
  "deidentifyConfig": {
    "infoTypeTransformations": {
      "transformations": [
        {
          "infoTypes": [
            {
              "name": "FIRST_NAME"
            },
            {
              "name": "LAST_NAME"
            }
          ],
          "primitiveTransformation": {
            "characterMaskConfig": {
              "maskingCharacter": "*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "item": {
    "value": "My name is **** *** and I live nowhere."
  },
  "overview": {
    "transformedBytes": "7",
    "transformationSummaries": [
      {
        "infoType": {
          "name": "FIRST_NAME"
        },
        "transformation": {
          "characterMaskConfig": {
            "maskingCharacter": "*"
          }
        },
        "results": [
          {
            "count": "1",
            "code": "SUCCESS"
          }
        ],
        "transformedBytes": "4"
      },
      {
        "infoType": {
          "name": "LAST_NAME"
        },
        "transformation": {
          "characterMaskConfig": {
            "maskingCharacter": "*"
          }
        },
        "results": [
          {
            "count": "1",
            "code": "SUCCESS"
          }
        ],
        "transformedBytes": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```